# Defer form submission to a method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form:

```
<form id="myForm" @submit.prevent="doSomething()">...</form>
```

In `doSomething()` I make a check and if true, I want to submit the form. How can I submit the form after the check?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Add a ref attribute to the form

You can add a `ref` attribute to the form element. Then, in the `doSomething` method, you can submit the form via `this.$refs.form.submit()`.

Template:

```
<form id="myForm" ref="form" @submit.prevent="doSomething()">...</form>
```

Vue component methods:

```
doSomething() {
  // do something
  
  this.$refs.form.submit();
}
```

For more info on refs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

### Pass the event object to the method

You can also pass the event object to `doSomething` by adding the `$event` param. This gives the method a reference to the target element:

Template:

```
<form id="myForm" @submit.prevent="doSomething($event)">...</form>
```

Vue component methods:

```
doSomething(e) {
  // do something
  
  e.target.submit();
}
```

Comment: $event is undefined in the case of @submit.prevent="doSomething($event)"

Comment: @Sergey No it's not: https://jsfiddle.net/fc0skjh8/ Must be something specific to your case. Do you have an example of this happening?

Comment: @thanksd haha, it's working today to me too. How weird. Sorry anyway, not sure what it was.

Comment: this is not working for me. It gives me ````not a function```` for both cases